# How to import spring bean's configuration file in Maven dependency to an other in my Maven project?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, xml-import

I add local maven repository, I add the local dependency in my project.
this dependency encompass a Spring configuration file .
I want to import this file in an other spring configuration file.
What should I do ?

knowing that the dependency tree that includes the file to be imported is as follows:
{dependencyXXX}.jar>{PackageByDefault}>springInjectDateAsString.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just put this in your application context:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/springInjectDateAsString.xml" />
```

Comment: as a reward, I offer the following jar and maven installation with:  Download this jar :  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60615128/delivred/abdennour/spring/springBeansReadyByAbdennour1.0.0.1.jar                              To Install :
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=<DOWNLOADED_PATH>/springBeansReadyByAbdennour1.0.0.1.jar -DgroupId=slm.abdennour.tn.archetypes -DartifactId=abdennour-java-quickstart -Dversion=1.0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=<HOME_PATH>/.m2/repository